# Como faço para enviar um Dado selecionado no SELECT2 pelo method=POST?

Tags: php, jquery

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
<label>Cidade</label>
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width:100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option selected="selected" value = "0">Selecione</option>
<?php
$result_situacao = "SELECT * FROM `tabela_cidades`";
$con = $conn->query($result_cidade) or die($conn->error);
while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $dado['id_cidades']; ?>" name = "cidade"><?php echo $dado['nome_cidades']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Mas quando vou capturar o dado usando essa declaração:

> $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cidade']);

Aparece o erro:

> **Notice**: Undefined index: cargo in C:\wamp64\www\sistema\paginas\processos\cad_clientes.php on line 5

Acredito que estou fazendo errado para pegar o valor seleccionado no plugin *jQuery* SELECT2, mas não sei o que está errado.

Comment: Já tentou dar um `print_r( $_POST);` para verificar que variáveis foram passadas via POST?

Comment: Quem é $result_cidade ? E pra que serve $result_situacao ?

Comment: Mude o atributo "name" coloque ele no select e não nas options. Além disso confira se suas variáveis $result_cidade e $result_situacao está corretas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O name deve ser no select  `<select name = "cidade"....` e não no option

> ```
> Sintaxe:
>  <select name="NOME" size="ALTURA">
>    <option value="VALOR A PASSAR">VALOR MOSTRADO</option>
>    <option value="VALOR A PASSAR">VALOR MOSTRADO</option>
>    <option value="VALOR A PASSAR">VALOR MOSTRADO</option>
>  </select>
> ```

```
<label>Cidade</label>
<select name = "cidade" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width:100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option selected="selected" value = "0">Selecione</option>
```

A variável no while não bate, $result_situacao e não $result_cidade **OU VICE-VERSA**

```
<?php
$result_situacao = "SELECT * FROM `tabela_cidades`";
$con = $conn->query($result_situacao) or die($conn->error);
while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $dado['id_cidades']; ?>"><?php 
echo $dado['nome_cidades']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Realmente a variável estava incorreta e o "name" estava no option e o correto era no <select>